# elasticsearch - delete specific indices from snapshot

Tags: snapshot, elasticsearch

I used [Snapshot And Restore | Elasticsearch Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) to setup snapshot, however I did not specify which one of many indices I need to take snapshot of, which lead to 390 (at the moment) unneeded indices in my snapshots, which takes unnecessary resources:

```
# curl http://0:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/_all?pretty | grep -cE '(filbeat|logstash)-2016'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 62055  100 62055    0     0  4908k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 5050k
390
#
```

My environment:

```
# curl 0:9200
{
  "name" : "k_slO6-",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "dvoVw1oaTN2V_8f3BLEYhQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.0.1",
    "build_hash" : "080bb47",
    "build_date" : "2016-11-11T22:08:49.812Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.2.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
#
```

On Debian 8:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
8.6
# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
# uname -a
Linux X 4.8.6-x86_64-linode78 #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 14:51:21 EDT 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
#
```

Is there a way to delete specific indices from snapshot?

Comment: @GregL I tried `curl -XDELETE 0:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/2016-11-24/?pretty -d '{"indices":"*2016*}'`, but that deleted entire snapshot(